# Debug Intellij usando Classpath com Projeto

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij

Olá, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Estou iniciando com Intellij, hoje tenho um projeto aonde utilizo outros projetos, e para fazer o debug dos subprojetos, no eclipse adiciono em Classpath "User Entries", se não adicionar não consigo usar o breakpoint.
Como fazer isso no Intellij?

[image: Exemplo eclipse:]

Answer (score 0):

No seu caso, segue esses passos:

1. Abra `Project Structure`, basicamente o `Project Settings`.
2. Selecione `Modules`.
3. Você deve estar vendo essa tela:
   [image: Project]
4. Em `Sources`, você pode adicionar a sua outra aplicação usando `Add Content Root`.

### Que tal usar Maven ou Gradle?

Normalmente utilizo maven/gradle para gerenciar minhas dependências. Fica bem mais simples. Nesse caso você só localizaria o src quando estive-se debugando.

Mais detalhes:

1. [Maven](https://maven.apache.org)
2. [Gradle](https://gradle.org)

### Interessante

Um outra maneira é usar o -Xbootclasspath.
Mais detalhes podem ser achado [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/JRCLR/optionx.htm#i1018570). Basicamente você vai adicionar uma nova variável à VM quando inicializar.